# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Label'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I have a gif that I have animated and I get a type error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 36, in <module>
    animate(last_frame,label,framelist,0)  # Start animation
  File "Untitled.py", line 4, in animate
    if frame_number > last_frame:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'Label'
```

It worked when the def was inside the main loop. But I need to have the animate loop out side. So I was wondering if I need to do something to convert it

```
import tkinter as tk
def animate(frame_number,last_frame,label,framelist):
    #if the frame number is bigger than the last frame
    if frame_number > last_frame:
        frame_number = 0
        #how long each frame should last
    label.config(image=framelist[frame_number]) 
    window.after(1500, animate, frame_number+1)
#make mainwindow
window = tk.Tk()
# List to hold all the frames
framelist = [] 
# Frame index
frame_index = 0    

while True:
    try:
        # Read a frame from GIF file
        part = 'gif -index {}'.format(frame_index,fr)
        frame = tk.PhotoImage(file='giphy.gif', format=part)
    except:
        # Save index for last frame
        last_frame = frame_index - 1 
         # Will break when GIF index is reached
        break              
    framelist.append(frame)
     # Next frame index
    frame_index += 1       


#put the gif into a label
label = tk.Label(window, bg='black')
label.grid(column = 1, row = 7)

animate(last_frame,label,framelist,0)  # Start animation
#window size
window.geometry("600x600")

#end of page
window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error is telling you that you cannot compare the 2 objects because they are not the same type. What line does your traceback say this is happening on. My guess is `if frame_number > last_frame:` Your functions positional arguments do not match up with what you are passing to the function. Try to change this: `animate(last_frame,label,framelist,0)` to this `animate(0, last_frame,label,framelist)`

Comment: Are you sure your `framelist` has something in it? Index out of range mean that nothing exist at that index or rather that index doesnt exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are passing arguments in the wrong order to your function.

Change this line:

```
animate(last_frame, label, framelist, 0)
```

To this line:

```
animate(0, last_frame, label, framelist)
```

Taking a closer look at your code I noticed if you do not have a valid `gif` then it will break on the 1st loop. If you do have a valid `gif` file then you will run into a problem with your `after()` statement.

Change your `after()` statement to be this:

```
window.after(100, animate, frame_number+1, last_frame, label, framelist)
```

Here are the changes I made to this this to work. Keep in mind you have to be targeting a valid gif or it will break from the start.

```
import tkinter as tk


window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("600x600")
framelist = []
frame_index = 0


def animate(frame_number, last_frame, label, framelist):
    if frame_number > last_frame:
        frame_number = 0
    label.config(image=framelist[frame_number])
    window.after(100, animate, frame_number+1, last_frame, label, framelist)

while True:
    try:
        part = 'gif -index {}'.format(frame_index)
        frame = tk.PhotoImage(file='./Images/giphy.gif', format=part)
    except:
        last_frame = frame_index - 1
        break
    framelist.append(frame)
    frame_index += 1

label = tk.Label(window, bg='black')
label.grid(column=1, row=7)

animate(0, last_frame, label, framelist)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I changed it, and I got this now ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Masterpoject.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "Masterpoject.py", line 15, in main
    mainpage()
  File "/Users/Darsh/Documents/Master Project/car.py", line 65, in mainpage
    animate(0, last_frame,label,framelist)  # Start animation
  File "/Users/Darsh/Documents/Master Project/car.py", line 8, in animate
    label.config(image=framelist[frame_number]) 
IndexError: list index out of range```

Comment: @DarshPatel That is a separate problem from the one my answer solved. Your first error was due to the position of your arguments. This new error is a problem with your code and your framelist.

Comment: @DarshPatel taking a closer look at your problem it appears to be your `while True` statement failing right away so there is never a frame to append to the `framelist` therefor bad index when you try to read the 1st non existent index.

Comment: yea I know that fix that issue I need to fix this other error that I have.

Comment: @DarshPatel then take a look at your code and if you cannot work out what is causing the new error come back and ask a new question about that problem. I have already pointed out where your issues starts so see what you can do with that. I am actually trying to fix your overall code right now but I am not sure what the `part`  portion of your code does.

Comment: I fixed my code now I will create a new question for the other error that I have

Comment: @DarshPatel I have updated my answer with the fix for your code.